# I am getting Exception: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'client' where client is defined as a foreign key on a one to many relation

Tags: django, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Here are the log entries around the prolem.

```
2023-09-25 10:29:25,768 - facebookapi.fetchMetadata - CRITICAL - about to save to master
2023-09-25 10:29:25,771 - facebookapi.fetchMetadata - CRITICAL - Master exists now update...
2023-09-25 10:29:25,773 - facebookapi.fetchMetadata - CRITICAL - _master.save() Exception: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Here are the two models Client and Master

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True),
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    #more fields abbreviated

class Master(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_metadata = models.JSONField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null = True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null = True)
    #more fields abbreviated
```

and the code that is generating the error.

```
logger.critical("about to save to master+++++++++++++++++++++OOOOOOOOOOOO+++++++++++++")

        try:
            _master = Master.objects.filter(client=client_fk) 
            if _master is None:
                logger.critical("Master does not exist now create...")
                new_master = Master.objects.create()
                new_master.client = client_fk
                new_master.user_id = user_id
                new_master.user_name = result["name"]
                new_master.user_apprequests = _connections1["apprequests"]
                new_master.user_business_users = _connections1["business_users"]
                new_master.user_businesses = _connections1["businesses"]
                new_master.user_accounts = _connections1["accounts"]
                new_master.user_adaccounts = _connections1["adaccounts"]
                new_master.user_assigned_ad_accounts = _connections1["assigned_ad_accounts"]
                new_master.user_assigned_pages = _connections1["assigned_pages"]
                new_master.user_permissions = _connections1["permissions"]
                new_master.user_personal_ad_accounts = _connections1["personal_ad_accounts"]
                new_master.user_metadata = result["metadata"]
                new_master.account_status = "created"

                new_master.save()
            else:
                logger.critical("Master exists now update...")
                logger.critical("Master.client: %s", _master.client)
                #_master.client = client_fk
                _master.user_id = user_id
                _master.user_name = result["name"]
                _master.user_apprequests = _connections1["apprequests"]
                _master.user_business_users = _connections1["business_users"]
                _master.user_businesses = _connections1["businesses"]
                _master.user_accounts = _connections1["accounts"]
                _master.user_adaccounts = _connections1["adaccounts"]
                _master.user_assigned_ad_accounts = _connections1["assigned_ad_accounts"]
                _master.user_assigned_pages = _connections1["assigned_pages"]
                _master.user_permissions = _connections1["permissions"]
                _master.user_personal_ad_accounts = _connections1["personal_ad_accounts"]
                _master.user_metadata = result["metadata"]
                new_master.account_status = "updated"

                _master.save()

            return Response("Master saved", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical("_master.save() Exception: %s", e)
            return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I tried changing the filter to "client_id" , I tried modifying the model so client becomes client_id, and migrating but the error complains cannot find client_id_id

I tried dropping the foriegn key, then migrating, then adding it back and migrating again, but to no avail

What can I try next?  Should i create a new Master2 mode?  Should I kill all migrations and start over?

The goal is to have a new record created if there isn't one and update the current record if there is one.

Should I abandon the whole foreign key think and use code to ensure the relation instead?

Thanks,

MO

Comment: I changed the filter to client_id=client_fk and got a different exception...

Comment: I changed the filter to client_id=client_fk and got a different exception...- _master.save() Exception: Cannot resolve keyword 'client_id' into field. Choices are: account_currency,... click_to_call_call_confirm, clicks, client, <<<note it says to the choice is client but it didn't like client before.  is this an internal bug?

Comment: changed it back to client and ..._master.save() Exception: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'client'

Comment: tried client__id=client_fk and got a new exception...Unsupported lookup 'id' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change 'filter' to 'get' and the problem went away.